# FCM handling issues while working with both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently I use both

```
{"notification" : { "body" : "hello world"}}
```

and

```
{"data" : { "body" : "hello world"}}
```

push notification is received, there isn't any problem at all.

Problem comes when I try to create a custom notification (I got my own reason why I would like to do so). So when I implement both data-message and display-messages (notification tray), `onMessageReceived` wasn't called and I know that this is normal after I studied this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-android-background).

So I can't eliminate the notification tray due to the way how iOS works, but instead I need to overwrite Android's notification which is sent to the system tray. Is it really possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best choice right now is to send different messages to different devices. You can either track which platform the registration token is for (if sending directly) or use split topics (e.g. mytopic-ios and mytopic-android). Then you can customise the send based on the destination.

Comment: I didn't notice you do answer this question. Ya eventually I using the method you suggest but which on my way to achieve the outcome. Thank for reply I will accept your answer.

Comment: I find this is still true sadly....